# django aggregate over reverse generic foreign key

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models, InvitationAccept refers Invitation with GFK.

I don't want to define `accepts` GenericRelation because I don't want `cascade delete` when I delete InvitationAccept instances.

```
class InvitationAccept(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    invitation = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Invitation(models.Model):

    accepts = generic.GenericRelation(InvitationAccept)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

> Note also, that if you delete an object that has a GenericRelation,
>   any objects which have a GenericForeignKey pointing at it will be
>   deleted as well. In the example above, this means that if a Bookmark
>   object were deleted, any TaggedItem objects pointing at it would be
>   deleted at the same time.

But then I would like to get #accepts 
I could use `self.filter(user_invite=user).annotate(num_accepts=Count('accepts__id')).aggregate(Sum('num_accepts'))` if I had `accepts` field.

So how do I not have `accepts` (not cascade-delete) and query the above aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count accepts per invitation for a user, right? Maybe you should just use something like:

```
qs = (InvitationAccept.objects
      .filter(invitation__user_invite=user)
      .annotate(Count('invitation', distinct=True))
      .values('invitation', 'invitation__count'))
```